# preventDefault() not working on a particular option select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this `<select>` list that takes different options and reroutes based on the one clicked. The html code is:

```
      <select id="pageSelect" name="Choose Page" onchange="location = this.value">
        <option value='' disabled selected hidden>Choose Page</option>
        <option value='/page-1'>Page 1</option>
        <option value='/page-2'>Page 2</option>
        <option value="allPages" >Custom Page</option>
      </select>
```

The rerouting of the first 2 pages work as expected. However, the third option is going to be handled using a custom Javascript function instead of being handled by the onchange function declared at the `<select>` element.

The custom function for the last `<option>` is:

```
   $('#pageSelect').change(function(event) { 
      event.preventDefault()
        var pagesvalueselect = $(this).val(); 
        if(pagesvalueselect=="allPages"){ 
            $('#siteSaleModal').modal("show"); //Open Modal
        }
    });
```

The function works and when a user clicks on the last option, it triggers the modal to pop up but it still redirects the user to another page based on `value="allPages"` even though I am using the `preventDefault()` function.

Comment: Have you tried moving all of the `onchange` into the jQuery event? They could both be triggered.

Comment: Default action refers to what normally happens if you don't have event handlers hooked up.  Since you have event handlers it's going to trigger them.  Since you are setting two separate handlers on "change" I suggest you turn them into one handler which has the smarts to redirect or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `preventDefault()` call only stops the *current* `change` event handler. The one you've assigned via the `onchange` attribute will still run regardless as it's entirely separate.

To fix this, and improve your code, remove the `onchange` attribute (as they are outdated and now considered bad practice) and combine them in to one unobtrusive event handler.

```js
$('#pageSelect').change(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault()
  var pagesvalueselect = $(this).val();
  if (pagesvalueselect == "allPages") {
    console.log('open modal...');
    //$('#siteSaleModal').modal("show"); //Open Modal
  } else {
    console.log('redirecting to ' + pagesvalueselect + '...');
    //window.location.assign(pagesvalueselect);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="pageSelect" name="Choose Page">
  <option value="" disabled="true" selected="true" hidden>Choose Page</option>
  <option value="/page-1">Page 1</option>
  <option value="/page-2">Page 2</option>
  <option value="allPages">Custom Page</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code code works fine without `event.preventDefault()` and `onchange` attribute.

```
<select id="pageSelect" name="Choose Page">
  <option value='' disabled selected hidden>Choose Page</option>
  <option value='/page-1'>Page 1</option>
  <option value='/page-2'>Page 2</option>
  <option value="allPages" >Custom Page</option>
</select>

$('#pageSelect').change(function(event) { 
    var pagesvalueselect = $(this).val(); 
    if(pagesvalueselect=="allPages"){ 
        $('#siteSaleModal').modal("show"); //Open Modal
    } else {
        location = pagesvalueselect;
    }
});
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/smraikode/pen/rNaXPQr)